# Relationship between the ideal gas constant and entropy

Tags: gas-laws, entropy

So it dawned on me the other day that the ideal gas constant $$R = \pu{8.31 J mol-1 K-1}$$ has the same units as molar entropy. Is there some deeper meaning behind this or is it just a coincidence that this occurs?

Comment: Well, R is in the equation for the entropy change of an ideal gas at constant temperature.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: What is that, equation as it may answer my question. But, i was asking why does R have the units for entropy - Is it representing entropy?

Comment: Both entropy and the ideal gas constant are in some sense related to the Boltzmann constant.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that please. How are they related?

Comment: $\Delta S=R\ln{(V_f/V_i)}=-R\ln{(P_f/P_i)}$

Comment: Is V and P referring to pressure and volume for initial and final

Comment: Unfortunately, a discussion of why $k_{B}$ is related to entropy may be beyond the scope of this discussion if you don't already know that. You might just need to learn some statistical mechanics.

Comment: Yes, it's referring to pressure and volume for an isothermal change of an ideal gas.

Answer (score 6):

The gas constant is equal to Avogadro's constant times Boltzmann's constant, the latter serving as a proportionality constant between the average thermal (kinetic) energy of the particles in an ideal gas and the temperature:

$$\left(\frac{\partial \bar U}{\partial T}\right)_p=\frac{3}{2}k_\mathrm{B}$$

The entropy can be regarded as a proportionality constant between the change in free energy $G$ with change in temperature of a system at constant pressure, since

$$\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_p=-S$$

Note also that the average entropy of a particle can be written as

$$S=k_\mathrm{B} \log\Omega$$

So both $R$ and $S$ can be regarded as proportionality constants between energy and temperature.

The Wikipedia page on the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Relation_to_the_virial_theorem) may provide some enlightenment on the origin of these proportionalities.

Answer (score 6):

The fundamental equation is Boltzmann's for the entropy $S =k_B\ln(\Omega)$ where $k_B$, Boltzmann's constant, has units J/molecule/K.  When we use $R$ instead of $k_B$ it is trivially because molar units are used to define $S$.

In the equation $\Omega$ is the number of arrangements or configurations (or 'complexions' to use an old word) of distinguishable 'particles' among all the available energy levels. In that sense entropy is a measure of the uniformity of population in these levels.

(If there are $N$ distinguishable particles  then $\displaystyle \Omega =\frac{N!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!\cdots}$ where there are $n_i$ particles in level $i$. The log is evaluated by assuming all the numbers $N,\, n_i$ etc. are large numbers so that Stirling's approximation for $\ln(N!) $ etc. is valid.)

Answer (score 1):

In the ideal gas, $3R/2$ is the thermodynamic entropy of one Mol.

The factor $\frac{3}{2}$ comes from $ST=N\bar{E}=N\frac{3k}{2}T=\frac{3R}{2}T$.

The energy of 1 Mol of ideal gas is either given by $3pV/2$ or $3RT/2$ or $ST$.

(In the ideal gas) *the entropy does not depend on temperature*.
That is why one writes the $T$ separate in $TS$.
For non-ideal gases $S$ changes with temperature: $E=\iint dSdT$.

For the ideal gass $C_V = S$ (always per Mol here).
$ST = \int dQ_{\text{rev}} = C_V \int dT = S \int dT$.
Because of constant volume, all the energy goes into $T$.
$C_V$ and $S$ stay constant.
On the $pV$ side this amounts to an increase in pressure.